# Android: Make screen "flash" white

Tags: java, android

I want to make my android screen "flash" white temporarily (only once). It needs to be long enough that the user will be able to tell that the screen did in fact turn white.

The user will land on a screen, which will flash white after 5 seconds, then display the original screen again (possibly fading from white).

What would be the best way to do this? Right now I am creating a rectangle that takes up the entire screen and programatically showing and hiding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Add a foreground by creating an overlaying (*match_parent* size) ImageView and set *android:src* to a white drawable.
- Set the visibility of this view to *android:visibility="gone"*.
- When you want to show the white flash, I recommend an animation to fade the white flash in and display it.

This is a basic animation which will fade in an ImageView's drawable. The fade out will be the reverse of this.

```
public static void FadeIn(final ImageView v,
        final int begin_alpha, final int end_alpha, int time,
        final boolean toggleVisibility) {

    if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        v.setImageAlpha(begin_alpha);
    else
        v.setAlpha(begin_alpha);

    if (toggleVisibility) {
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    v.setImageAlpha(end_alpha);
                else
                    v.setAlpha(end_alpha);

                if (toggleVisibility) {
                    if (v.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else
                        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {
                int new_alpha = (int) (begin_alpha + (interpolatedTime * (end_alpha - begin_alpha)));
                if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    v.setImageAlpha(new_alpha);
                else
                    v.setAlpha(new_alpha);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration(time);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

You could, instead of creating a new view, use the android:foreground property if you're using a framelayout and toggle the opacity from 0 (transparent) to 1 (opaque). (NB. For the first method, when the flash view is visible, you won't be able to interact with any elements under it, which makes this a better option than a FrameLayout with a foreground property). This is harder to implement, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can get the flash to work, but I am having trouble with the timing. It looks like the code that runs the animation takes much longer to complete (about a second later than everything else). It almost appears as if this waits until everything else is done to run. Is there a way to set timings of animations? I am running very similar code to yours in a Runnable with no luck

Comment: The timing issue was caused by the Android camera. Thanks again!